# why arguments of a function cannot be declared val or var

Tags: scala

Why the arguments of a function cannot be defined as `val` or `var`?

```
scala> def add2(val x:Int) = x+2
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but 'val' found.
def add2(val x:Int) = x+2
         ^

scala> def add3(var x:Int) = x+3
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but 'var' found.
def add3(var x:Int) = x+3
         ^

scala> def add2(x:Int) = x+2
add2: (x: Int)Int
```

Comment: `var` would be an evident side effect and tend to bad pratice

Comment: Function argument is `val` by default `scala> def add2(x:Int) = x=3
<console>:11: error: reassignment to val
       def add2(x:Int) = x=3`

Comment: Note: `add2` is not a function, it is a method.

Comment: It's unclear what meaning you want `val` to have here. As for `var`, allowing it seems like a plausible language extension, but I believe it was omitted on purpose, and it probably won't ever be allowed. In general, Scala prioritizes immutability, and providing some way to make method parameters be assignable just isn't necessary.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Both Scala and Java are call by value when it comes to the function parameters. So what difference will it make ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am copy pasting a text from *Programming in Scala 3rd edition*

> "Any parameters to a method can be used inside the method. One important characteristic of method parameters in Scala is that they are vals, not vars.The reason parameters are vals is that vals are easier to reason about. You needn't look further to determine if a val is reassigned, as you must do with a var."

Answer (score 0):

One cant use var or val in method parameter, because method parameter is by default val so there is no reason to say val name: type.

method parameter are val by default because var parameter are prone to error.